# Get data from Javascript fetch and display it in another function

Tags: javascript

I thought it would be easy to find an answer to this, but it wasn't. I'm trying to make an api call from a function and then display the response in a different function. What I've got or what I want to achieve:

```
async getData() {
   const response = await http.get("/api/");
}

async showData() {
   const result = await this.getData();
   console.log(result);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: `getData` does not return anything.  And `const` are block scoped.

Comment: `getData()` isnt returning anything ...

Comment: Remove async from getData and return http.get('/api/') from it.

Comment: `return response` in `getData`…?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getData` method shouldn't need to be declared `async`. Just make `showData` an `async` method and `await` the `getData` response.

```js
const getData = () => fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(response => response.json());

const showData = async () => {
  const result = await getData();
  console.log(result);
}

showData();
```

Here is the altered code:

```js
getData() {
   return http.get("/api/");
}

async showData() {
   const result = await this.getData();
   console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and your time, I appreciate it! I'm not that confident in fetch or api calls.